# How can a creature gain Intelligence while stunned by an Intellect Devourer?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, conditions

If a creature's intelligence is reduced to 0 via an Intellect Devourer's Devour Intellect ability, they are stunned until they regain at least 1 point of INT. So how can a stunned creature go about gaining INT? Can a creature that is both stunned and has an INT of 0 attune to an item such as a Headband of Intellect or an Ioun Stone of Intellect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You cannot attune to those items while stunned

The DMG says about attunement:

> Attuning to an item requires a creature **to spend a short rest focused on only that item** while being in physical contact with it (this can't be the same short rest used to learn the item's properties). This focus can take the form of weapon practice (for a weapon), meditation (for a wondrous item), or **some other appropriate activity**.

Therefore, you cannot attune to something if you cannot dedicate your focus to it, because attunement is an activity. A stunned creature is unable to do this.

### Greater Restoration will fix it

To recover from ability score damage, you need the spell Greater Restoration, which says in its description:

> [...]  or end one of the following effects on the target:
>
> - Any reduction to one of the target’s ability scores

You can also replicate the spell with Wish, or if you can secure a scroll or Ring of Spell Storing, you can also do that to cast this spell.